# Jquery resizing table header columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, resize

I am trying to resize jquery table header columns. I can do it with in a single table but I am unable to do that if header is with fixed table header.

My jsfiddle trials are below:

[With Single Table Header:](http://jsfiddle.net/chandana2014/AETZH/)

[With Fixed Table Header:](http://jsfiddle.net/chandana2014/AETZH/1/)

How can I make fixed table header work with a resize pointer at end of th text?

```
$(function() {
    var pressed;
    var start;
    var startX;
    var startWidth;
    var wrapper = $("div#wrapper");
    var container = $("table#fixedHeaderTable");

    $("table th").mousedown(function(e) {
        start = $(this);
        startX = e.pageX;
        startWidth = $(this).width();
        $(start).addClass("resizing");
        pressed = true;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(pressed) {
            var newWidth = startWidth + (e.pageX - startX);
            start.width(newWidth);
            wrapper.width(container.width() + 10);
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if(pressed) {
            $(start).removeClass("resizing");
            pressed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a little correction to the code you wrote. Please find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/mhRd3/1/)

I added following lines to your code. Hope it helps

```
contentColumn = $('#contentsTable').find('td').eq($(this).index());

contentColumn.width(newWidth);
```